# How to show/hide check boxes in ListView programmatically

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have next problem: I use following adapter to populate ListView:

```
public class PlaylistCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

public PlaylistCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView playlistTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View view){

        checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        playlistTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.playlistTitle);
    }
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    int playlistName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);
    String playlist = cursor.getString(playlistName);

    viewHolder.playlistTitle.setText(playlist);
}
}
```

As you can see, I have checkbox in the row which is gone in the very beggining and what I want to do is to show all of them(checkboxes) when onItemLong is performed.

Actually I already implemented onItemLong in my activity and I was nearly done with that task with following code:

```
 public void showCheckBoxes(){
    for(int i = 0; i != playlist.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {

        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) playlist.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

The method works fine until you can see all items in ListView on a screen.
But then I noticed that (mCheckBox = (CheckBox) playlist.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);) - is actually new problem, because if my listview is longer than screen, I always get the following error - (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference) and then app crashes.

Yep, I understand why is it happens, but have no idea how to solve the problem.

Will really appreciate if someone will give me answer, hint, link or some idea how to solve the problem.

Is it somehow possible to change code to show/hide checkboxes. Maybe there is a way to do that without calling .findViewById all the time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried without using the viewHolder? I've never used one and have had no problems making views visible/gone within the adapter.

Comment: Hello, yes, in the very beggining there wasn't ViewHolder in adapter class and I implemented it after I noticed the problem. I thought that it will work, but because I call .findViewById on checkbox in activity it doesn't work both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following

```
public class PlaylistCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

public boolean isAllItemsVisible;

public PlaylistCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

public static class ViewHolder{
CheckBox checkBox;
TextView playlistTitle;

public ViewHolder(View view){

    checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    playlistTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.playlistTitle);
}
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, viewGroup, false);
ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
view.setTag(viewHolder);
return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
if(isAllItemsVisible)
    viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
int playlistName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);
String playlist = cursor.getString(playlistName);

viewHolder.playlistTitle.setText(playlist);
}
}
```

I just take one boolean called `isAllItemsVisible` to maintain the visibility of the all items.

For showing the all the `checkbox` you just need to call the following method.

```
public void showCheckBoxes(){
   mplaylistCursorAdapter.isAllItemVisible=true;
   mplaylistCursorAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Try this! Hope it's works for you!

Comment: Hello, THANK YOU VERY MUCH, maaaan, that works perfect, you're star, you know that?:) Sorry I can't make plus 1 to your answer right now, because I have only 11 reputation right now(I'm a bit newby in here), but will do it for sure. Thank you, that's great!

Comment: @LevanVoronin Happy to help! Cheers!